# MySQL SELECT несуществующих столбцов

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Есть единый для множества таблиц запрос:

```
SELECT one, two, three FROM ? WHERE id = ?
```

Не во всех этих таблицах есть столбцы one, two и three. Как сделать так, чтобы при наличии этих столбцов выбрались их значения, а при отсутствии был NULL?

Comment: Прекратить использовать "единый" запрос и перейти на индивидуальные.

Comment: @Akina, мне нужен гибкий универсальный инструмент, а не огромный набор костылей с if'ами или switch/case'ами. Если MySQL это не умеет, то MySQL не нужен. Must die.

Тогда другой вопрос, какая из реляционных СУБД с SQL такое умеет и куда малой кровью и быстро можно перенести таблицы из MySQL?

Comment: Ни одна СУБД подобного бреда не потерпит. Делай хранимую процедуру, реализующую логику работы с метаданными и выбор подходящего запроса. *мне нужен гибкий универсальный инструмент* В первую очередь тебе надо усвоить, что SQL и недетерминированность ходят разными дорогами.

Comment: @Akina, ясно, спасибо. В очередной раз убедился в убогости и ненужности SQL и реляционных БД, за 40 с лишим лет так и не сделали ничего путного. Лучше буду хранить свое добро в виде json в Redis: быстрее, удобнее, а следовательно - лучше.